# value property of input field in react not responding

Tags: reactjs

The input field is not accepting any values .This is the render component

```
<Row>
    {this.state.activitieslist.map((newrow,index)=>{
            return (
                <Col sm={12}>   
                    <Row className="form-row">
                        <Col sm={12}>
                            <div className="form-input">
                                <InputGroup>
                                    <InputGroup.Addon className="activity-ul"><i className="fa fa-circle"></i></InputGroup.Addon>
                                    <FormControl type="text" name="ngo-activities-undertaken" placeholder="enter your activity" value={this.state.activitieslist[index].activities} onChange={this.handleActivityChange.bind(this,this.state.activitieslist[index],index)}></FormControl>
                                </InputGroup>
                            </div>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Col>)
            })
        }
</Row>
```

and I have the states as an object array as

```
this.state = {
        activitieslist : [
            {rowValues : 'a', activities : ''},
            {rowValues : '', activities : ''}
        ],
```

I am not able to enter values in the input field. it does not reflect any values that I enter

the handleActivityChange function is given below

```
handleActivityChange(activitieslist,id,e){
 console.log("event " + e.target.value+" index "+id+"activitieslist"+activitieslist.activities)
   this.setState({[activitieslist.activities ]: e.target.value})
}
```

Please do help me out as I am new to react.

Thanks in advance :)

**this is my updated code**

```
<Row>
                    {this.state.activitieslist.map((newrow,index)=>{
                            return (
                                <Col sm={12}>   
                                    <Row className="form-row">
                                        <Col sm={12}>
                                            <div className="form-input">
                                                <InputGroup>
                                                    <InputGroup.Addon className="activity-ul"><i className="fa fa-circle"></i></InputGroup.Addon>
                                                    <FormControl type="text" name="ngo-activities-undertaken" placeholder="enter your activity" value={this.state.activitieslist[index].activities} onChange={(e)=>{this.handleActivityChange(this.state.activitieslist[index],index,e)}} ></FormControl>
                                                </InputGroup>
                                            </div>
                                        </Col>
                                    </Row>
                                </Col>)
                            })
                        }  

                </Row>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Row>
                {this.state.activitieslist.map((newrow,index)=>{
                        return (
                            <Col sm={12}>   
                                <Row className="form-row">
                                    <Col sm={12}>
                                        <div className="form-input">
                                            <InputGroup>
                                                <InputGroup.Addon className="activity-ul"><i className="fa fa-circle"></i></InputGroup.Addon>
                                                <FormControl type="text" name="ngo-activities-undertaken" placeholder="enter your activity" value={this.state.activitieslist[index].activities} onChange={this.handleActivityChange(this.state.activitieslist[index],index)}></FormControl>
                                            </InputGroup>
                                        </div>
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </Col>)
                        })
                    }  

            </Row>
```

replace with above code

and below code in your component contructor

```
this.handleActivityChange=this.handleActivityChange.bind(this)
```

Comment: Then how do i get the target value.please give me the function also

Comment: onChange={(e)=>{this.handleActivityChange(this.state.activitieslist[index],index,e)}}

Comment: even after trying this values are not updating.